# Space at the bottom and right side of my page

Tags: html, css, space

This is the page: [propertytest.uphero.com](http://propertytest.uphero.com)

I have narrowed down the problem to the 6 blueish boxes (the top 3 are under a div called offers and the 3 below that are under a div called properties). If I was to take them out, the space goes but I would really like to keep them in so I need someone to help me troubleshoot it so that I can keep the boxes and have no space below the footer.

I think my problem lies with the fact they are positioned with relative (all divs are positioned relative - bad idea I now realize that).

I have tried:

- aligning the 2 divs with absolute positioning - that does the trick of getting rid of the space at the bottom/right however if I was to scale down the browser, the boxes go out of position..
- removing all positioning and floating them to the left/right - removes the space at the bottom/right but doesn't go into the position I would like them to ( I don't think you can position floats with top/bottom/left/right or margin? )

Comment: What browser is the problem occurring in? I cant see anything wrong in Chrome

Comment: @Sam its occuring in all browsers, I have tried the latest IE, Chrome, Firefox aswell as IE8. It might be because of my smaller resolution? (im on a laptop)

Comment: Do you mean you wish to stick the footer to the bottom of the page?

Comment: @RyanMurphy thanks for the reply, I tried that and added it to the 2 div id's and it got rid of the right side space and not the bottom it also made the images like 5 pixels wide

Comment: @ikartik90 I would like it beneath all of the divs. so yes, basically :D

Comment: @PeterAllen Im putting together an alternative layout for your page which should sort the problem, give me a few minutes

Comment: @PeterAllen Glad I could help somewhat, even if limited

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to sort out the 6 boxes that you currently have as position:relative;

http://jsfiddle.net/F9Q6T/

The basic premise is that you float the boxes inside a container and then clearfix them to make the container the right size.

In terms of the issue at the bottom of the page you need to remove bottom:290px; from your footer. This appears to be what is causing the problem

Comment: I have added the code that you have provided and this has happened: http://propertytest.uphero.com/ all of the space has gone (thank you!) however, the boxes havent done what I would like them to do, should I try position relative? I would like to change the images separately later on

Comment: Did you add this into your css?

.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}

Comment: Yeah, I  did layout the html like this tho:<div id="container">
  <div class="box"><img src="images/offers_box.png" alt="offersOne" /></div>
  <div class="box"><img src="images/offers_box.png" alt="offersTwo" /></div>
  <div class="box"><img src="images/offers_box.png" alt="offersThree" /></div>
  <div class="box"><img src="images/offers_box.png" alt="offersFour" /></div>
  <div class="box"><img src="images/offers_box.png" alt="offersFive" /></div>
  <div class="box clearfix"><img src="images/offers_box.png" alt="offersSix" /></div>
</div>​

Answer (score 0):

I think main  problem is `body background image. You have used image of 1300px * 1000px size`. i think you must use `image of 1px width with repeat property.`. And white space at bottom come due to `bottom` property of orders and properties div`

thanks.

Comment: I have changed it to a 8x8 jpg with repeat x and y. I would love to get rid of the bottom property but if I do, the boxes go out of position. I really need to get around that but nothing seems to be working..