# space at the bottom of my page

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Space at the bottom and right side of my page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685467/space-at-the-bottom-and-right-side-of-my-page)

First off, I am sorry for posting this twice, my previous question earlier got good replies but they did not fix my problem..  so I am posting it again to hopefully get some more answers (I really need to fix this issue!)

Link for the actual [page](http://www.propertytest.uphero.com)

Basically, at the bottom of my page between the offers/properties div and the footer there is a big space. I know why this is; I have used relative positioning and used top: -256px; to position the boxes where they are.

I have tried:

Aligning the 2 divs with absolute positioning - that does the trick of getting rid of the space at the bottom and I can get the boxes where I want them however if I was to scale down the browser, the boxes go out of position..(is there a way to get around that?)

Removing all positioning and floating them to the left/right - removes the space at the bottom/right but doesn't go into the position I would like them to

Sam on my previous question did [this](http://jsfiddle.net/F9Q6T/), it sorts of my problem just I can get them into position!

Adding `overflow: hidden;` to the container div.

I just don't know what to do so any help is really appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to edit your original question

Comment: first of all dont repost it will get flagged and deleted. Second I suggest using jsfiddle to show all your code its a website that is trivial to use and it helps other people to see your code. Also make sure your website looks anything like you want it too in firefox because i viewed it in Aurora 14.02 and space at the bottom is not the only problem i have found.

Comment: Re think it.  Use a table if you need to..

Comment: Some of your problems could be related to html that is not valid. 31 Errors, 1 warning(s)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Just saw that you got that answer already.. The next step is to put those boxes in a container.

```
<div id="offer_box_wrap"></div>
```

style

```
#offer_box_wrap {
width: 650px;
float: left;
margin-left: 5px;
}
```

you'll have to tweak it but it should work

**end EDIT**

You are relatively positioning your left boxes so...

i would suggest this

do not use `<li>` for boxes

use a div with a class that aligns them as you want.

```
<div class="offer_box"></div>
```

style it

```
.offer_box {
width: 208px;
height: 170px;
background: url(http://www.propertytest.uphero.com/images/offers_box.png) no-repeat;
float:left;
margin: (figure out the spacing you need for 3 per row)
}
```

put a clear div underneath the last one

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

see it here http://jsfiddle.net/atTGa/2/